# SQL Select statement - multiple tables allow null values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do realise that problem I am facing is not a rocket science but still, I did not find any information about fixing this.

I have multiple tables in my database (`PSQL`) I want to create a `select` query to make a reporting function for my app.

Here is my query:

```
select 
    s.id, s.name, st.name, p.firstname || ' ' || p.lastname, 
    f.name, f.store_date, bdt.name, bd.comment 
from  
    system s, systemstatus st, role w, person p, file f, 
    documenttype bdt, document bd 
where 
    w.system_id = s.id and 
    p.id = w.person_id and 
    st.id = s.status_id and 
    bd.system_id = s.id and 
    bd.file_id = f.id and 
    bd.type_id = bdt.id and 
    bd.role_id = w.id;
```

Query works I get `300` rows fully filled with values I am searching for. Problem is that I have about `1000` rows in `System` Table. It is possible that there is no `Person` or `Document` which could be linked with particular `System`.

I would like to see all rows that are in my `System` table (I mean about 1000), and when I can't link `Person` or `Document` with `System` I want the field to be null ( now it is not shown at all)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main part of the answer is - you need [left outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join).
Additional parts of the answer - use [ANSI join syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) and format your queries:

```
select
    s.id, s.name, st.name, p.firstname || ' ' || p.lastname, f.name,
    f.store_date, bdt.name, bd.comment
from system as s
    left outer join systemstatus as st on st.id= s.status_id
    left outer join role as w on w.system_id = s.id
    left outer join person as p on p.id = w.person_id
    left outer join document as bd on bd.system_id = s.id and bd.role_id = w.id
    left outer join documenttype as bdt on bdt.id = bd.type_id
    left outer join file as f on f.id = bd.file_id
```

Always remember that somebody will read your code someday (may be it will be future you :) ) - so readability counts!

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting your tables in query via "where" clause, which is equal to inner join. Instead you should left join Person and Document tables to System table, e.g.:

```
select * 
from system s
left join role w on w.system_id = s.id
left join person p on p.id = w.person_id
```

Comment: I will try this and keep You posted. Thank for advice !